# virtual function and modified this pointer

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, vtable, abi, virtual-functions

Consider the following code

```
class B1 {
public:
  void f0() {}
  virtual void f1() {}
  int int_in_b1;
};

class B2 {
public:
  virtual void f2() {}
  int int_in_b2;
};


class D : public B1, public B2 {
public:
  void d() {}
  void f2() {int temp=int_in_b1;}  // override B2::f2()
  int int_in_d;
};
```

and the following memory layout for the object d:

```
d:
  +0: pointer to virtual method table of D (for B1)
  +4: value of int_in_b1
  +8: pointer to virtual method table of D (for B2)
 +12: value of int_in_b2
 +16: value of int_in_d

Total size: 20 Bytes.

virtual method table of D (for B1):
  +0: B1::f1()  // B1::f1() is not overridden

virtual method table of D (for B2):
  +0: D::f2()   // B2::f2() is overridden by D::f2()
```

---

```
D  *d  = new D();

d->f2();
```

When `d->f2();` is invoked, `D::f2`  needs access to data from `B1`, but modified this pointer

```
(*(*(d[+8]/*pointer to virtual method table of D (for B2)*/)[0]))(d+8) /* Call d->f2() */
```

is passed to `D::f2`, then how is `D::f2` able to access it?

The code is taken(and modified) from :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table#Multiple_inheritance_and_thunks

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'mdified this pointer'. Everything is working nicely, because D has both  B1 and B2 in it. When D::f2 is generated, it knows how to access int_in_b1 usign offset from the this.

Comment: @SergeyA http://codepad.org/4DIgwoMe see the output.

Comment: I posted some really dumb comments earlier, please forgive them.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're actually asking here. Do you have some code that is misbehaving, or are you just asking how things work?

Comment: @EJP I am just asking how things work.

Comment: @q126y Note, that in your link, the D inherits from B1 and B2 in different way than in your question (they are swapped), so there when you print this of B1, it is actually this of B1, while D::f2 prints always prints this of D. Actually, in the base classes, it is always this of the base class. Only that for simple inheritance, this pointer does not need to be adjusted, so it would be equal to that of the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your case is actually too simple: The compiler can know that you have a pointer to a `D` object, so it can perform the lookup from the right table, passing the unmodified `this` pointer to the `f2()` implementation.

---

The interesting case is, when you have a pointer to `B2`:

```
B2* myD = new D();
myD->f2();
```

Now we start with an adjusted base pointer, and need to find the `this` pointer for the whole object. One way to achieve that would be to store an offset alongside the function pointer that is used to produce a valid `this` pointer from the `B2` pointer used to access the vtable.

Thus, in your case, the code might implicitly be compiled like this

```
D* myD = new D();
((B2*)myD)->f2();
```

adjusting the pointer two times (once deriving the `B2*` from the `D*`, then the inverse using the offset from the vtable). Your compiler may be clever enough to avoid this, though.

In any case, this is firmly within the field of implementation. Your compiler can do *anything*, as long as it *behaves* the way the standard specifies.

Comment: For each virtual function, there should be `(base x, offset)` for each base class pointer from which it can be called? Am I correct? 

The above situation will occur in diamond inheritance using virtual inheritance.

Comment: With the method I sketched, you need exactly one pair of function pointer and `this` offset for each virtual function. That pair would reside within the vtable of the base that first introduces the virtual function. If that introducing base class is a virtual base, you would need to resolve the `this` pointer to that virtual base first, just as you did in the static case.

Comment: https://ideone.com/UXRHZ6 in this case `derived::fun()` can be called from `base1 *`, `intermediate *` and will need different offset.

Comment: When I do `myIntermediate->fun()` in your example class hierarchy, the compiler can first do the virtual base resolve `base1* converted = myIntermediate;` implicitly, and then proceed to generate the code for `converted->fun();`. That is, the compiler only ever needs to look up the pair for `fun()` from a single vtable. Of course, it also needs to be able to resolve the positions of all virtual bases of a class. I guess that's another entry for each virtual base in the vtables of derived classes. These virtual base entries of the vtables would be entirely distinct from the function pointers.

Comment: when you say `another entry for each virtual base in the vtables of derived classes`, do you mean another entry for each virtual function? That is what I was saying in my first comment. function entry will be one, but it will have offset for various base classes alongwith it.

Comment: No, I meant exactly one entry for each virtual base, independent of all the function pointers that may exist in the same vtable. As I said in my last comment, the call `myIntermediate->fun()` can be decomposed into two actions. To resolve the correct base class pointer (`base1* converted = myIntermediate;`), you need the virtual base entry in the vtable of `Intermediate`. To subsequently dispatch the virtual function call (`converted->fun()`), you need the pair of function pointer + offset stored for that function.

Comment: did you mean function pointer + offset for the base, when you said `you need the pair of function pointer + offset stored for that function.`

Comment: The vtable would have two different kinds of entries: 1. virtual base offsets, and 2. pairs of (virtual function pointer, offset for `this`-adjustment). 1. would be used in `base* converted = myIntermediate;`, 2. would be used in `converted->fun();`. 1. would be per virtual base class, 2. would be per virtual function. Does that clarify things?

Comment: ah, now I get it. say `d1:virtual public b1, virtual public b2` and `d2:virtual public b1, virtual public b3` and `d3:public d1, public d2` `d3` will have memory layout something like `b1|b2|b3`. then `b1` will have different offset for `d1` and `d2` in vtable of `d3`. Did I get it right?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the effect you are describing as "modifying a `this` pointer" is an implementation detail of some particular compiler.   There is no specific requirement that a compiler modify pointers like you describe.

There is also no requirement that an object have vtables, let alone that they are laid out like you describe.  The actual requirement is that the correct overload of a virtual function will be called at run time, and that it will be able to correctly access data members and call member functions.   Now, in practice, compilers tend to use vtables, but that is an implementation detail because alternatives are less efficient by various measures.

Now, that said, the following discussion will assume every class with a virtual function has a vtable.   Looking at your example, what does this do?

```
D  *d  = new D();

d->f2();
```

The first thing is that the compiler knows that `d` is a pointer to `D`, and knows that `D` has a function named `f2()`.   It will also know that `f2()` is a virtual function inherited from `B2` (which is one reason that it is not possible to call a class member function unless the compiler has visibility of the complete class definition).

In this case, we know what `d` and `D` are, so we know `D::f2()` should be called, with the `this` pointer equal in value to `d`.     The compiler has the same information (it knows `d` is a `D *`) so it just does that.   Now, okay, it might or might not look up `D::f2()` in the vtable, but that is the end of it.

The more interesting example, like cmaster said, is

```
B2* myD = new D();
myD->f2();
```

In this case, `myD` is a pointer to `B2`.   The compiler knows that `B2` has a virtual function named `f2()`, so knows it has to call the correct overload.

The thing is, in the statement `myD->f2()`, the compiler might not know that `myD` actually points to a `D`  (e.g. the construction of the object and the calling of the member function might be in different functions, in different compilation units).    However, it does know that a `B2` has a virtual function named `f2()`, which is required to call the actual overloaded version correctly.

This means the compiler needs two bits of information.   Firstly it needs information identifying the actual function (`D::f2()`) to be called.   The second bit of information will be some adjustment of `myD` to make the call of `D::f2()` work correctly.   This second bit of information is essentially what is needed to produce (what you are calling) the "modified `this` pointer" from `myD`.

If the compiler does all this with the help of vtables, it might include BOTH bits of information in the vtable for `B2`.   So (assuming the second bit of information is an offset) the compiler turns

```
myD->f2();
```

into something like

```
(myD + myD->vtable->offset_for_f2)->(myD->vtable->entry_for_f2)();
```

The part `(myD + myD->vtable->offset_for_f2)` is essentially what you are describing as "the modified `this` pointer" which `D::f2()` will see when called.  The part `(myD->vtable->entry_for_f2)` is essentially the address of `D::f2()`  (say the address of the member function).

The next question to ask is how might the compiler populate the vtable?    The short answer is that it does this when constructing the object.

```
B2* myD = new D();
```

The new expression (`new D()`) essentially expands to

```
void *temp = ::operator new(sizeof (D));    // assuming class does not supply its own operator new

//  construct a `D` in the memory pointed to by temp

temp = (D *)myD;    // the compiler knows we're creating a D, so doesn't use offsets or anything funky here
```

The process of turning the memory pointed to be `temp` into a `D` is the important thing.   Firstly, it invokes constructors of base classes (`B2` and `B2`), then constructs or initialises `D`s members, then it invokes `D`'s constructor   (the C++ standard actually describes the order of events in exquisite detail).    The other thing is that the compiler does bookkeeping to ensure we actually get a valid `D` from the process.   Part of that is populating the vtable.

Now, since the compiler has complete visibility of the definition of class `D` (i.e. complete definition of base classes, its members, etc), it has all the information needed to populate the vtable.  In other words, it has all the information it needs to give sensible values to both `myD->vtable->offset_for_f2` and `myD->vtable->entry_for_f2`

In the case of multiple inheritence, assuming one vtable per base class, the compiler has all the information it needs to populate all the vtables in a similar way.    In other words, the compiler knows how it lays out objects in memory, including their vtables, and uses that knowledge appropriately.

But, then again, it might not.   As I said, vtables is a technique commonly used in compilers to implement/support virtual function dispatch.   There are other ways too.

Answer (score 0):

again i can't comment so must answer here.

is no problem in the code!

> `D::f2` needs access to data from `B1`
>
> then how is `D::f2` able to access it?

just write in `D::f2`, `B1::int_in_b1` then you ca access to int value.

Comment: Actually, OP doesn't even need to qualify with `B1::int_in_b1`, OP can simply say `int tmp = int_in_b1` and it should work just fine.

Comment: in his case, yeah it dos't need it!
but really i don't know what he need to answer him!
this code works as expected!
In polymorphism the right write with OP.

Comment: The way I read this question, it is not about how to write C++ code that works, but about how the compiler can produce a working executable from this C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, when d->f2() is called, compiler knows that d is a pointer to class D. To call f2(), it would adjust the pointer of d to be "this" of B2 before passing it to virtual f2(), as you describe. Now, inside of the D::f2(), the compiler knows that this is D::f2() and it knows how D inherits from B2, and so it fixes the "this" of B2 to be "this" of D in the very beginning of the function, so when your code executes it would see that "this" is that of D. Therefore it can access any members of D inside of D::f2().
If you would have had

```
B2* b = d;
b->f2();
```

When b->f2() is called, the pointer being passed to f2() is "this" of B2. Inside D::f2(), the passed pointer is fixed to point to this of D.